# Alt attribute in external css file

Tags: html, css

One simple question.
Is there any way to add an image's alt attribute in an external css file in order to avoid more inline css characters?

For example something like this:

```
#my_img{
alt: "my image";
}
```

Comment: alt is the property of img html tag. It's not for the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Possible to give this method. In CSS or CSS3 alt values does not able to set.
and also  this not css characters.

Answer (score 1):

NO by using javascript it is possible.
     var t = document.getElementById('imgName');
     t.setAttribute('alt', 'new alt');